# How can I define instance of arg with type Enum

Tags: typescript, enums, mapping

I have a function which takes enum and returns value from one of two dictionaries.

Each dictionary has own enum as key. How can I refer to the correct dictionary, depending on the received enum?

Maybe I need to use another type?

```
enum firstSet {
  key1 = 'key-1',
  key2 = 'key-2',
  key3 = 'key-3',
}

enum secondSet {
  key1 = 'key-1',
  key2 = 'key-2',
  key3 = 'key-3',
}

type IDictionary1 ={
  [key in firstSet]: string
}

type IDictionary2 ={
  [key in secondSet]: string
}

const testDictionary1: IDictionary1 = {
  [firstSet.key1]: 'translate1',
  [firstSet.key2]: 'translate2',
  [firstSet.key3]: 'translate3'
}

const testDictionary2: IDictionary2 = {
  [secondSet.key1]: 'secondTranslate1',
  [secondSet.key2]: 'secondTranslate2',
  [secondSet.key3]: 'secondTranslate3'
}

const f = (key: firstSet | secondSet) => {
  ???
  const correctDictionary = `key from firstSet` ? testDictionary1 : testDictionary2
  ???

  return correctDictionary[key]
}
```

I can check each values in each enum, but it is really unproductive.

Comment: This question is somewhat ill-posed because at runtime these keys are just going to be, for example, `"key-1"` for both enums, so there's no way to distinguish which enum they came from.  You need to change them so as not to conflict, and then once you do that you should just look up the key in the dictionaries instead of in the enum, perhaps like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NV7PBm) shows.  Does that fully address your question?  If so I will write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly noted above - you need to think in terms of the code being compiled.
Enum value compiles just to 'string', and impossible define original type. So you can based on original enum object.
The best solution to this question is to create a factory that takes an enum object and returns functions, each using its own dictionary. Inside the factory, a mapping is made between the enum object and the dictionary.
The question code only has two dictionaries, so I'm using the ternary operator for the logic example:

```
const getF: {
    enumObj: typeof firstSet | typeof secondSet
}: (key: firstSet | secondSet) => string = {
    const dictionary = enumObj === firstSet ? testDictionary1 : testDictionary2
    return (key: firstSet | secondSet) => {
        return dictionary[key]
    }
}
```

But for my task, I included the dictionary name as a prefix in the enum value.

```
enum firstSet {
    key1 = 'testDictionary1:key-1',
    key2 = 'testDictionary1:key-2',
    key3 = 'testDictionary1:key-3',
}
```

And I parse them inside the function `f: (firstSet | secondSet) => sring`

Answer (score 1):

Enums are just objects at runtime, for example, your `firstSet` will look something like this:

```
const firstSet = {
  key1: 'key-1',
  key2: 'key-2',
  key3: 'key-3',
}
```

So you can check if key is a value in object as you always would:

```
  const correctDictionary = Object.values(firstSet).includes(key) ? testDictionary1 : testDictionary2
```

Note however that this just tests for string equality. If a key exists in both enums, you will always end up with the first.

There is a package [ts-enum-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util) which has operators for that (not sure if I would recommend it though).

Comment: You imply that there will be [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html?#reverse-mappings) for a string enum, but that's not true; only numeric enums have reverse mappings.

Comment: but now `key in firstSet` will always be `false` because `key` is the *value* of the enum

Comment: @jcalz jupp, didn't pay attention, thanks again